# Connecting to MySQL with .NET Connector and SSL. Does it need a client certificate?

Tags: .net, mysql, ssl

I am considering establishing an encrypted connection from a .NET app toward a remote MySQL database. According to the [manual](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-net-en.pdf), there is a SSL Mode option to do that. The example provided in the tutorial rely on a client X509 certificate. Is the client certificate absolutely needed, or can I just connect with `SSL Mode=Required` and a login/password in the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL always implies having certificate at least on one side of the connection.  If your set-up is not critical you can use either self signed certificate or better get one for free from cacert.org